# Has anyone a recipe of Yuengling beer?

Tags: recipe

As a visitor of the US, I have learned to appreciate Yuengling beer. Did someone try to brew a clone of this beer and can publish a recipe?

Comment: Recipe questions are considered 'off-topic' http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11/recipe-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about their "Traditional Lager"? They have several different beers, though this one is the most popular I believe.

At the request of some Pennsylvanians, I made a clone once, cobbled together from a few different recipes on the web. It was well received.

60% - Pale 2-row
17% - C60
23% - corn grits,
- Target 1.045 OG

You'll probably want to do a cereal mash first, and then a saccharification rest at 151ºF (66ºC) for a full 90 minutes.

You want about 20IBUs of bittering from a traditional neutral hop, perhaps cluster, and then I understand there's a small 15 minute addition of Cascade. I used 0.5oz (15g) for 5 gallons (19L).

Ferment with a clean lager yeast and then give it a nice long cold storage before serving.

Good luck! Let us know how it turns out if you make it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed Tradional Lager from America's oldest brewery. I'll give it a try and let you know how it was.